# Skipping Message Boxes in Excel VBA When Running Multiple Macros Based on a Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that runs multiple codes based on a condition in Excel VBA. The condition is determined by a column, and if the value in that column is "Yes" the corresponding code is executed. If there are multiple "Yes" values in the column, each associated code runs consecutively.

The issue is that each code displays a message box, and I have to manually close it before the next code can run. I want to avoid or skip these message boxes in Excel VBA.

Below is the original VBA code:

```
Sub RunMacrosBasedOnCondition2()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet where your data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Routines") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

    ' Find the last row with data in Column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Disable display of alerts (message boxes)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Loop through the rows in Column A and check the condition in Column B
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Yes" Then
            ' Assuming the macro name is stored in Column A
            On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors if the macro doesn't exist
            Application.Run ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
        End If
    Next i

    ' Enable display of alerts (message boxes)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Message box can be with different description here is the example

[image]

Comment: Instead of messagebx, why not use `Debug.Print "Message"` in those procedures? That ways you will not have to handle it. Or use a modeless form to show those messages?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding! The issue I'm facing is that I have over 50 codes. If I manually change the pattern of each code, it will consume a significant amount of time. There are two buttons - one is causing a message box to pop up every time the code runs, and for the other one, I want to prevent the message box from popping up and allow the remaining codes to run smoothly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/safer to keep macro names and the such entirely in VBA? It's more plausible someone (accidentally) editing a cell in Excel.

Comment: I appreciate it! and this is long run to handle it this way and i will definilty do it later, but for now i have to figure out something which can accomplish this.

Comment: From the searching I've done for now, they all point towards having an optional argument in the Subs to show/skip the message boxes but that would still include all of them having to be adjusted. Then, when calling the sub from another sub, you pass it along with a `False` or something similar to not have the message boxes pop up (there needs to be an if statement around the message boxes then).

Comment: Where are the macros located, are all 50+ in a module ?

Comment: Yeah you are right! @Notus_Panda

Comment: Yes each code in separate module @CDP1802

Comment: Do you mean there are 50+ modules ?

Comment: Almost! Yes you are right, I do not run the that codes at once, only 8 to 10 or less codes run using the `Yes` condition

Comment: And do you know the modules name of the those 8 to 10 involved in processing of "the `Yes` condition"? Then, are there in those modules some other subs using MsgBox which shouldn't be stopped? I mean, theoretically it is possible to programmatically find all `MsgBox` code lines from the respective module and comment them. And also reversing the operation. But it also depends on the way the code is written. I mean, if there are consecutive lines separated by `:` it is still possible but the `MsgBox` to not also be followed by code lines after `:`...

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, thanks for your comment. If it's possible to automatically click the 'Ok' button for each message box that appears, that's good. However, if we need to close or delete the message box, it might cause issues in the calculation. I'm trying to find a solution where the code can press the 'Ok' button whenever a message box shows up during the code execution.

Comment: Depending on the way the code is written, it is also possible to insert a condition above the respective code line (something as `If boolYes Then` and `End If` after the MsgBox code line. You can do it once and then only manipulate the `Public` boolean variable `boolYes`...

Comment: HSHO I am afraid we speak different languages and I am not referring to English, no offence... So, it is extremely complicated to create another application able to detect the MsgBox windows and automatically press the OK button. Possible, but more complicated than what I suggested above. Did you, at least, try understanding what I meant? It is also possible to (programmatically) replace MsgBox with something else, able to show the message for a second then closing itself, but collecting of the existing message is not so simple if I cannot see your code. Did you design the code in discussion?

Comment: Yeah Bro! I totally understand what you said, I know its very very diffcult to understand something without seeing the code. Is there a way where i can share the file with you personally.

Comment: When you intend addressing to me, it is necessary to use the tag... Then, I don't think is necessary to send the file, if you are able to determine/show the involved modules name and some examples of MsgBox used there. I mean, to see a pattern if it is similar to them. Then, how would you better like to proceed? To comment them, to use a different message box able to stay only a second, something else? Anyhow, I will leave my office in about 10 minutes. If you will clearly describe what you want (from what I offered...) I will try helping after reaching my home (in some hours).

Comment: I think if you want it project wide then use @FaneDuru tip. Do a public bool in a module like DoShowMessage then do a find and replace over the project to replace MessageBox with If DoShowMessage  then MessageBox or if you use call then  Replace Call MessabeBox with If DoShowMessage  then call MessageBox. Then do an Debug and find problems like messageboxes with a question.
Or you do a find on your project for messageboxes and just paste the if Construct in front after checking. This should take less then a couple of minutes.
And on the start sub just set the bool.

Comment: Are you still interested in finding a solution? Should I understand that not you designed the code and it looks complicated to identify the involved modules? Did you think that sending the workbook to me, I will do that instead of you?

Comment: Yes i need the solution @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to use `MsgBox` in VBA... That's why I required a general (used) pattern. I mean, you can use such a message displaying Yes/No buttons, based on which of them the user pressed to do something else. You (I) can programmatically write events containing `MsgBox`, the message itself can be written on many lines (ending in `VbCrLf & _`) and some other ways. The next code is able to treed (place the message line(s) inside an `If` - End If` statement, solving messages patern as the next ones:

```
'....
Sub testFirst()
  If 2 = 2 Then
    MsgBox "Correct"
  End If
End Sub

Sub SecondTest()
  If 2 = 2 Then MsgBox "This is OK"
End Sub

Sub TheNextCase()
  If 2 = 2 Then MsgBox "this is OK " & vbCrLf & _
                       "but it is on two (theoretical) lines..."
End Sub

Sub testAnsMsgbox()
  Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult
  ans = MsgBox("do you want it as it is?", vbYesNo, "Message confirmation")
  If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

1. You need to copy the next code in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Private arrMsgBModules
Public boolWithMess As Boolean

Sub testMsgBoxInModulesList()
 'if the array with MsgBox is empty:
 If Not IsArray(arrMsgBModules) Then ExtractFoldersWithMsgBox
    
  MsgBoxInModulesList arrMsgBModules, "MsgBox ", ThisWorkbook
End Sub

Sub MsgBoxInModulesList(modArr, strFind As String, wb As Workbook)
   Dim codeM As VBIDE.CodeModule, boolUnderScore As Boolean, spNo As Long
   Dim boolFound As Boolean, el, st_line As Long, en_line As Long
   
   For Each el In modArr
        Set codeM = wb.VBProject.VBComponents(el).CodeModule
        st_line = 1
        Do
           boolFound = codeM.Find(strFind, st_line, 1, -1, -1)
           If Not boolFound Then Exit Do
           spNo = SpaceNo(codeM.Lines(st_line, 1))
           If InStr(codeM.Lines(st_line - 1, 1), "boolWithMess") = 0 Then
                codeM.InsertLines st_line, String(IIf(spNo = 0, 0, spNo - 1), " ") & "If boolWithMess then"
                If Right(codeM.Lines(st_line + 1, 1), 1) = "_" Then '+ 1 for the newly inserted line...
                     boolUnderScore = True
                 Else
                     boolUnderScore = False
                 End If
                codeM.InsertLines st_line + IIf(boolUnderScore, 3, 2), String(IIf(spNo = 0, 0, spNo - 1), " ") & "End If"
            End If
           st_line = st_line + IIf(boolUnderScore, 4, 3)
        Loop Until Not boolFound
   Next
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function SpaceNo(strLine As String) As Long
  Dim i
  For i = 1 To Len(strLine)
    If Mid(strLine, i, 1) = " " Then
        SpaceNo = SpaceNo + 1
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
  Next i
End Function

Sub ExtractFoldersWithMsgBox()
  Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent, VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject, CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
  Dim i As Long
  
  'redim the array to keep all modules having MsgBox
  ReDim arrMsgBModules(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count)
  
  For Each VBComp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        ' Check if the VBComponent is standard module:
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
            Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
            If CodeMod.Name <> "modFaneDuru" Then 'exclude this module
                'find Msgbox in iterated modules:
                If CodeMod.Find("MsgBox ", 1, 1, CodeMod.CountOfLines, 1, False) = True Then
                    arrMsgBModules(i) = CodeMod.Name: i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
  Next VBComp
  If i > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve arrMsgBModules(i - 1)
  End If

End Sub
```

2. You should run `testMsgBoxInModulesList` from above:

```
Sub testMsgBoxInModulesList()
 'if the array with MsgBox is empty:
 If Not IsArray(arrMsgBModules) Then ExtractFoldersWithMsgBox
    
  MsgBoxInModulesList arrMsgBModules, "MsgBox ", ThisWorkbook
End Sub
```

It will process the messages code sample presented above and transforme it in:

```
'....
Sub testFirst()
  If 2 = 2 Then
   If boolStopMess Then
    MsgBox "Correct"
   End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub SecondTest()
 If boolStopMess Then
  If 2 = 2 Then MsgBox "This is OK"
 End If
End Sub

Sub TheNextCase()
 If boolStopMess Then
  If 2 = 2 Then MsgBox "this is OK " & vbCrLf & _
                       "but it is on two (theoretical) lines..."
 End If
End Sub

Sub testAnsMsgbox() 'not affected...
  Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult
  ans = MsgBox("do you want it as it is?", vbYesNo, "Message confirmation")
  If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

3. Your buttons will call the same `Sub` having a `Boolean` parameter, in the next way:

```
Sub RunWithMsgbox()
   RunMacrosBasedOnCondition True
End Sub

Sub RunWithoutMsgbox()
   RunMacrosBasedOnCondition False
End Sub
```

4. Of course, you can see a variable `Public boolWithMess As Boolean`, **on top of the module**, to be used in order to make the main sub working with or without MsgBoxes...

As I said above some `MsgBox` patterns type are not processed. The above code can adapted to solve/process all cases, **if the respective patterns are clearly described.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much; I appreciate your response with a nearly complete solution. However, I apologize for not opting for the 'testMsgBoxInModulesList' approach, as it would still require me to make code modifications. I've gone through your message about sending the workbook personally. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it. @FaneDuru

Comment: @HSHO I am afraid, I cannot get you... So, you do not want to modify the code sending the messages, even if this modification is done automatically. Is this understanding a correct one? If so, what do you expect from me after looking to the code? If not, are you afraid that there also are more MsgBox pattern types? Should **I** look to the code you run and **look for** modules where to programmatically modify the MsgBox sequences to condition their execution using a `Boolean` variable? Or, what? I like helping people! But only when I clearly understand what are their expectations...

Comment: I apologize for not being able to explain clearly what I'm trying to achieve. Here's the line of code from my question that I want to keep: `If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Yes" Then`. All the code is executed based on this condition. I have assigned code names in Column 9, and if Column 8 is equal to "Yes," then run the specific code. I still want to use this pattern, and I want all the codes to follow the same pattern, even if I need to make modifications to the code. https://ibb.co/GPmZycw as per this image, I want to run those codes where Yes is mentioned With or without Message box.

Comment: @HSHO Isn't the code line you show (`If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "Yes" Then`) in the main routine **which calls other subroutines** where the mentioned MsgBox messages exist? If so, nothing will be changed in the respective routine. If not and such a condition is before the MsgBox code line, **it will remain as it is** and only the message line will be placed between the conditional `If - End If` statement. But, you can try it. Insert a new module, copy my above (first) example to be processed and **only replace `If 2 = 2 Then` with the respective one**. Name this module "testModule" and

Comment: @HSHO Place only this new model in the array: `modArr = Array("testModule") and run `testMsgBoxInModulesList()`.

Comment: @HSHO OK, you can send the workbook to me on my personal mail (from my profile). Please, announce me about it sending. Otherwise, it will go in Spam. I will look at it this evening when I will be at home.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to you sooner. I just saw your message by now. I have sent the workbook via email.

Comment: @HSHO I will look at the workbook you sent. I hope, you explained somehow the context related to your code way of working/processing...

Comment: @HSHO I did not clearly understand what your code globally does and I tried focusing on the issue of conditioning all MsgBoxes. I created a sub able to extract all modules having MsgBoxes (instead of nominating them) in an array and processing them from there. I will adapt the above code to include it.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your help!